# Include inside section doesn't work Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a `@section` inside my child template and I am trying to include another template inside of it, but It doesn't work.
My parent template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- X-csrf token -->

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    {{-- Custom CSS --}}

    @yield('head')

    {{-- Open Sans font --}}

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{{$title}}</title>
</head>
<body>

    @yield('content')

    @yield('footer')

</body>

    {{-- JS files --}}

    @yield('javascript')

</html>
```

My child template code:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

{{-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --}}

@section('head')

    {{-- Custom CSS for index page --}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/index.css')}}">

@endsection

{{-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --}}

@section('header')

    <header>

        @include('navbar')

    </header>

@endsection

{{-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --}}

@section('content')

    <section>

        <div class="entry-texts">

            <h1 class="entry-title">Welcome to my page!</h1>

            <h2 class="entry-subtitle">Must be some text in here.</h2>

        </div>

    </section>

@endsection

{{-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --}}

@section('footer')

    <footer>

    </footer>

@endsection

{{-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// --}}

@section('javascript')



@endsection
```

The problem is in this part:

```
@section('header')

    <header>

        @include('navbar')

    </header>

@endsection
```

It does not include my navbar in the header tag. My navbar file is located in `views` directory. What is the problem and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent template does not have `@yield('header')` and your `navbar` is in a section called `@section('header')`

Answer (score 1):

You are yielding **head** but using section **header**. This is the problem.
Use `@section('head')`

Answer (score 0):

just a little clarification. your head section should end with stop as in for yielding scripts and styles:

```
@section('head')

    {{-- Custom CSS for index page --}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/index.css')}}">

@stop
```

Comment: So I don't need an `@endsection` anymore?

Comment: yea. you dont need it

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- X-csrf token -->

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    {{-- Custom CSS --}}

    @section('head')

    {{-- Open Sans font --}}

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>{{$title}}</title>
</head>
<body>

    @yield('content')

    @yield('footer')

</body>

    {{-- JS files --}}

    @yield('javascript')

</html>
```